# Inequality Problem Related to a Spivak Problem (Ch 1 16(b))

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This question came up when I was looking at [a Spivak problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZpQ2.png), but I just want to check the step below. Given $$4{x}^{2} + 8xy + 4{y}^{2} \ge  0 $$

and
$$4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2} \le  0$$

> "Subtract the second equation from the first."

Is this the correct approach for this particular step?

$$4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2} \le  0 \implies -(4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2}) \ge  0$$

Now $$4{x}^{2} + 8xy + 4{y}^{2}  \ge  0  \land -(4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2}) \ge  0 \implies  2xy \ge 0 $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you assuming $4x^2+6xy+4y^2 \leq 0$? Also your deduction that $2xy \geq 0$ is not correct since $x$ could be negative and $y$ positive making their product negative.

Comment: You reference a particular solution (in this case, the author's), yet do not provide it as context, so we have no idea what was reasoned before the step in question.  We have no way to understand a single specific step in a proof that has not been provided.

Comment: @heropup I will edit my question, but did not want to clutter it with extraneous info.

Comment: @PedroAmaral I clarified the question. Sorry for the confusion, but I should have just stripped all the extraneous info and just concentrated on the step at issue. The fact that Spivak uses a particular construct, was, I realize irrelevant to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "correct", but you should not use "=" for $\implies$. This is typed with `\implies`. It is correct because you applied the rule
$$ a\ge 0 , b\ge 0 \implies a+b\ge 0 .$$

For reference, Spivak's solution is:

> (b) The first equation implies that
> $$
> 4 x^{2}+8 x y+4 y^{2} \geq 0
> $$
> Suppose that we also had
> $$
> 4 x^{2}+6 x y+4 y^{2} \leq 0
> $$
> Subtracting the second from the first would give $2 x y \geq 0$. If neither $x$ nor $y$ is 0 , this means that we must have $2 x y>0$; but this implies that $4 x^{2}+6 x y+y^{2}>0$, a contradiction.
>
> Moreover, it is clear that if one of $x$ and $y$ is 0 , but not the other, then we also have $4 x^{2}+6 x y+4 y^{2}>0$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your correction has been applied.

Comment: @user1115542 you're welcome; you can also consider

`\underbrace{4{x}^{2} + 8xy + 4{y}^{2}}_{  \ge  0}  + \underbrace{(-(4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2}))}_{ \ge  0} = 2xy \ge 0` $$\underbrace{4{x}^{2} + 8xy + 4{y}^{2}}_{  \ge  0}  + \underbrace{(-(4{x}^{2} + 6xy + 4{y}^{2}))}_{ \ge  0} = 2xy \ge 0$$

Comment: Nice and clean. Very appealing. Thanks